# How can i recover my video file in linux?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I have sucessfully recovered the photo from photorec but it doesn't recover video . How can I recover my video from my external memory card ?

Comment: You could try mp4fixer. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/519443/recovered-video-files-wont-play/1334772#1334772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in the following options;

```
bruteforce
Keep corrupted files
```

Also you should make sure you extract from the whole partition, not just un-allocated space.

Comment: it recover the .mp4 file but it is not played !! any reason ?

Comment: Looks like the recovered file is corrupted which can be due to a number of reasons, including partial overwrite or damaged media.  You can try following the answer here for repairing an MP4 http://superuser.com/questions/417100/how-to-open-and-repair-an-m4v-or-mp4-video-file